# Where is define? method defined? I couldn't find any document about it anywhere

Tags: ruby

Here's the sample codes:

```
class Square
  def initialize

    if defined?(@@number_of_squares)
      @@number_of_squares += 1
    else
      @@number_of_squares = 1
    end
  end

  def Square.count
    @@number_of_squares
  end
end
```

Comment: You rarely need to use `defined?`: `@@number_of_squares = (@@number_of_squares || 0) + 1`

Comment: @wuputah: I friendly disagree. Using `define?` you are not executing any expression, you are just checking if "that thing has any mean within the current scope". If the Square example can be rewritten as you suggest, `define?` has a lot of useful applications in a dynamic language like Ruby.

Comment: @Ibz: While `defined?` is definitely an important part of Ruby, I think `defined?` is a code smell in most situations. I believe that one shouldn't be branching your code based on locals existing or not existing. Instead, I'd recommend using `||=` or `||` as I did here. More complex situations where `defined?` is necessary usually points to a design problem.

Answer (score 4):

> defined? expression tests whether or not expression refers to anything recognizable (literal object, local variable that has been initialized, method name visible from the current scope, etc.). The return value is nil if the expression cannot be resolved. Otherwise, the return value provides information about the expression.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/files/keywords_rb.html#M000014

Answer (score 3):

`defined?` is actually a special operator, since it takes input in an unusual way. For example, you can call

```
defined? puts
```

and it will tell you `"method"`. You couldn't do this with a normal function.

Answer (score 2):

`defined?` is actually not a method but a unary prefix operator (just like `!`, `not`, `+@` and `-@`), but without the capability to override it. It wouldn't make sense to override it anyway, since its behavior cannot be implemented in Ruby.